# Redmi 4 heat issue

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I got Redmi 4 black few days back, my device is getting heat like anything while charging. I am using the charger included in the box. My colleague also having Redmi 4 black but he says he is not facing this issue. When I change the cable of charger the device not getting heat, but charging very slowly. Is there problem with charger cable or device? Any one facing this issue and have any resolution to get out of this issue?

Comment: Running MIUI8 right? Go to Security App, it contains every control of device. Goto battery section, check whether battery saver is ON, you can clear running apps that uses too much battery.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Miui8 China dev/Stable and using GApps, consider moving to miui.eu ROMs, GApps are not optimized because in China they don't use them. If you know what you are doing, migrate to any other miui (Miui EU, Miui Global are the best one, even if I dont know if there are any other MIUIs)